# Sharing Macro enabled workbook

Tags: vba, share

I created a workbook that I will have employee's enter certain bits of information via user form.  Multiple employees will be using this and I want them to be able to access it simultaneously.  Based on what I have seen online it does not seem that you can share a macro enabled workbook that allows for simultaneous use.  I tested this theory and sure enough the macro failed and I was unable to view/edit it since I had turned on sharing.

Has anyone had experience with this and found a way to work around it?  Our facility does not have a sharepoint drive currently that allows me to bypass these shared macro settings.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Why not use a database? Even Access can do all that you describe. Excel sharing is a sea of pain and misfortune.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can leave the workbook open on a shared drive and then distribute workbooks that call the macro in the shared drive.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few solutions that can probably help you:

**Google Spreadsheet**

- You can use a spread sheet to store the details and can share it with
  users using Google drive.
- Multiple users can edit it and read the document at the same time.
- You can read more of this in the link: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?hl=en&rd=1

**Microsoft Access Database**

- You can store the details into an access database.
- You can make use of a programming language such as C#.NET or Java to perform data access and query manipulations to serve your purpose.
- Ensure that all the users are accessing the same application and that the application is collected to the same database.
- You can read more of this in the link: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=175:connecting-to-microsoft-access-database-from-excel-vba-using-dao-object-model&catid=79&Itemid=475

**Manipulate Excel Data using VBA query and procedures**

- You can use the access queries and procedures with VBA which can serve your requirement.
- Please have a look at http://exceldesignsolutions.com/create-modify-and-run-and-access-query-with-vba/ if you are interested in following this method.